# Edit Using Dropdown - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have these two table in my database:

**tbl_province**

```
id | id_prov | prov_name
```

and

**tbl_district**

```
id | id_dist | id_prov | dist_name
```

and

**tbl_myhome**

```
id | id_prov | id_dist | name | address
```

and I have this controller for edit & update:

```
public function edit()
{      
    $this->load->model('m_login');    
    $level = $this->session->userdata('level');    
    $data['menu'] = $this->m_login->get_menu_for_level($level);    
    $data['title'] = 'District Data';   
    $data['content'] = 'district/v_edit_dist';    
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);    
    $this->db->where('id_dist',$id);     
    $q = $this->db->get('area_db');     
    if($q->num_rows()>0){       
        foreach($q->result() as $row){ 

            $data['id'] = $row->id;       
            $data['id_dist'] = $id_dist;
            $data['dist_name'] = $dist_name;
        }
    } else {
        $data['id'] = '';   
        $data['id_prov'] ='';
        $data['id_dist'] ='';
        $data['dist_name'] ='';
    }       
    $this->load->view('v_home',$data);     
}
```

And this is my v_edit_dist source on Dropdown:

```
<?php            
$q = $this->db->get('tbl_myhome');           
foreach($q->result() as $row){           
    $distname = $row->dist_name;            
?>   
    <select name="id_dist" id="id_dist" class="form-control">          
        <option selected="<?php echo $id_dist;?>"><?php echo $dist_name;?></option>
    </select>
```

When I tried to edit my data per-row, all the data's in the dropdown menu showed up, all the district name just showing up, and the district name in the form was wrong, it's showing the first district id, but actually in the database the data is the fifth district id.

I just confused how to make the district name on the dropdown match with the one in the database, and not all the district names shows up and messing the css. Please help..helep...I'm desperate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="id_dist" id="id_dist" class="form-control">          
    <option value="<?php echo $id_dist;?>"><?php echo $dist_name;?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add a description of what your code does (or what's different from the OP's) and why does it solve the issue. This is a suggestion to improve this and future answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
///// In controller file
public function edit()
  {
    $this->load->model('m_login');    
    $level = $this->session->userdata('level');    
    $data['menu'] = $this->m_login->get_menu_for_level($level);    
    $data['title'] = 'District Data';   
    $data['content'] = 'district/v_edit_dist';    
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);    

    $q = $this->db->get('tbl_district');     
    $district =  array();
    if($q->num_rows()>0){       
        foreach($q->result() as $row){ 
           $district[]= $row;
        }
    } 
    $data['id_dist'] = $id; 
    $data['district']= $district;
    $this->load->view('v_home',$data);     
}



// in view file

    <select name="id_dist" id="id_dist" class="form-control">          

    <?php            
        if(count($district)){
         foreach($district as $item){
    ?>   
            <option value="<?php echo $item->id_dist; ?>" <?php if($item->id_dist==$id_dist) echo 'selected';?>><?php echo $item->dist_name;?></option>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your view page

```
<select name="id_dist" id="id_dist" class="form-control">   
<?php            
$q = $this->db->get('tbl_myhome'); 
$result = $q->result();          
foreach($result as $row){ 

?>   

<option value="<?php echo $row->id_dist;?>" <?php if($row->id_dist==$id_dist){ echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $row->dist_name;?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>
```